# How do I access a data item from sqlite db and initialize it as a variable?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working on an android project an inventory management app.
I have tried to access the selling price of an oil from oil table in sqlite db to perform sale transaction where the price I have accessed from my db would be used as a variable in order to perform other arithmetic operations like calculating total and profit.
Also I need to keep the timestamp of the exact time the transaction happened separately,that is, date on a different column from time. I don't know why my code has an unsuccessful transaction. I need help.
The following is my code snippet:

```
    private void performOilSale(){
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextOccupied(editTextOilSaleCat, layoutOilSaleCat, getString(R.string.error_oilsale_cat))) {
        return;
    }
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextOccupied(editTextOilSaleQnty, layoutOilSaleQnty, getString(R.string.error_oilsale_qnty))) {
        return;
    }

    if (!databaseHelper.ifExist(editTextOilSaleCat.getText().toString().trim())){

        //listOil.clear();
        //listOil.addAll(databaseHelper.getAllOilCategory());

        Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd");
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") DateFormat longDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyy HH:mm:ss");//
        String category = editTextOilSaleCat.getText().toString().trim().toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String dbSp = "SELECT oil_bp FROM oil WHERE oil_category = " + category;
        Cursor catCursor; //db.rawQuery(dbSp,null);
        catCursor = db.rawQuery(dbSp,null);

        int unitPrice = Integer.parseInt(catCursor.getString(5));
        int saleOilQnty = Integer.parseInt(editTextOilSaleQnty.getText().toString().trim());
        int saleOilTotal = saleOilQnty * unitPrice;


        try{
            oilSale.setOilSaleDate(dateFormat.format(calender.getTime()).trim());
            oilSale.setOilSaleTime(timeFormat.format(calender.getTime()).trim()));
            oilSale.setOilSaleUprice(unitPrice);
            oilSale.setOilSaleQnty(Integer.parseInt(editTextOilSaleQnty.getText().toString().trim()));
            oilSale.setOilSaleTotal(saleOilTotal);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        databaseHelper.addOilSale(oilSale);
        Snackbar.make(relativeLayout, getString(R.string.oilsale_transact_success), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        catCursor.close();
        emptyTextFields();
    }
    else {
        Snackbar.make(relativeLayout, getString(R.string.oilsale_transact_error), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `String dbSp = "SELECT oil_bp FROM oil WHERE oil_category = " + category;`

You saying extract  data from the 1 column **oil_bp** from the **oil** table where the **oil_category** is as per whatever value is given as **category**.

Assuming this is valid. The resultant Cursor **catCursor** will have a number of rows (0-n) with a single column holding the value **oil_bp**

**Issue 1**
The Cursor will be positioned at **BEFORE THE FIRST ROW** (position -1). You cannot read data from the cursor until it is moved to a valid row. So an issue you have is that the cursor is not appropriately positioned.

You could use (assuming that you are sure that you will only retrieve 1 row) :-

```
if (catCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    // get the data here
}

- if there are no rows then the body of the if statement will not be entered.
```

or if you potentially have multiple rows (will also work for 1 row ) you can use :-

```
while( catCursor.moveToNext() {
   // get the data for each iteration here
}

- again no rows then the body of the while will not be entered.
```

**Issue 2**

The second issue you have is that the Cursors has just 1 column (not 6) so using `catCursor.getString(5)` will fail with an index error as there is no index to column 5. Instead as there is only 1 column it's index will be 0.

So you have to use `catCursor.getString(0)` or better use `catCursor.getString(catCursor.getColumnIndex("oil_bp")`. This will get the column index of the column named **oil_bp** if it exists in the cursor (else -1).

- Note you would not get a parse error if you used the Cursor's **[getInt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#getInt(int))** method instead of the Cursor's getString method to then parse it into an int.

**Issue 3 - possibly**

if the value of category is not a valid numeric then you would get a column not found error or perhaps a syntax error if it were a valid keyword, because non numeric literals need to be enclosed in single quotes. See extras 2/3 below and perhaps [SQL Language Expressions - Literal Values](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#literal_values_constants_).

**Extras**

**1**

To assist with debugging, if needed, you could use the **DatabaseUtils** **[dumpCursor(the_cusror_to_dump_aka_write_out_the_contents_to_the_log)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor(android.database.Cursor))** method.

- e.g. by adding the line `DatabaseUtils.dumoCursor(catCursor);` immediately after getting the Cursor. You can then check the log to see what the Cursor contains.

**2**

Use bound values rather than concatenation.

Instead of :-

```
    String dbSp = "SELECT oil_bp FROM oil WHERE oil_category = " + category;
    Cursor catCursor; //db.rawQuery(dbSp,null);
```

It is recommended to use :-

```
    String dbSp = "SELECT oil_bp FROM oil WHERE oil_category =?";
    Cursor catCursor; //db.rawQuery(dbSp,new String[]{category});
```

The SQLite API will then correctly enclose category in single quotes and also protect against SQL injection.

**3**

Although it may appear more long winded, it is recommended to use the SQLiteDatabase convenience methods rather than the rawQuery method, these build and execute the underlying SQL.

So instead of :-

```
    String dbSp = "SELECT oil_bp FROM oil WHERE oil_category = " + category;
    Cursor catCursor; //db.rawQuery(dbSp,null);
```

You could use the SQLiteDatabase **[query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))** convenience method e.g.

```
    Cursor catCursor = db.query("oil",new String[]{"oil_bp"},"category=?",new String[]{category},null,null,null);
```

**4**

You could use SQL to do the calculation e.g.

```
String dbSp = "SELECT oil_bp * ? AS saleOilTotal WHERE category=?";
catCursor = db.rawQuery(dbSp,new String[]{editTextOilSaleQnty.getText().toString().trim(),editTextOilSaleCat.getText().toString().trim().toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT)});
```

or using the convenience method :-

```
Cursor catCursor = db.query("oil",new String[]{"oil_bp * " + editTextOilSaleQnty.getText().toString().trim() + " AS saleOilTotal"},"category=?",new String[]{editTextOilSaleCat.getText().toString().trim().toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT)},null,null,null);
```

**Note** The code above is in-principle code, it has not been compiled or tested and may therefore contain some errors.